# Initializing a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, text-mining

I want to initialise a matrix with randomly generated numbers such that the sum of numbers in a row/column is 1 in 1 go.Both do not need to be 1 simultaneously i.e. either row sum is 1 or column sum is 1

Comment: Create the matrix (I named it myMat) then use `myMat <- myMat / rowSums(myMat)`

Comment: Should note that the `rowSums` solution provided by @Imo will not also work for `colSums` because of the matrix math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sum of rows = 1 you could try something like:

```
num_rows <- 5
num_cols <- 5

random_uniform_matrix <- matrix(runif(num_rows * num_cols), nrow = num_rows, ncol = num_cols)

random_uniform_matrix_normalised <- random_uniform_matrix / rowSums(random_uniform_matrix)

random_uniform_matrix_normalised
# [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
# [1,] 0.23587728 0.09577532 0.28102271 0.03763127 0.34969342
# [2,] 0.07252286 0.42979916 0.19738456 0.19545165 0.10484177
# [3,] 0.12868304 0.30537875 0.08245634 0.26911364 0.21436823
# [4,] 0.31938540 0.37610285 0.18834984 0.10297283 0.01318908
# [5,] 0.10775810 0.09167090 0.54077248 0.16717661 0.09262190
```

Comment: Thankss. This is it. Also could the same approach be used for colSums as well.